# How to perform SQL search based on words entered?

Tags: sql, contains

Is there a direct or easy approach to split words in entered search input and perform contains of first word from one column and second from other column ?

For example, if user enters "AARON KY" I need to search for records containing "AARON" in last name and "KY" in first name.

I know I can do this by performing sub-string using index for " " and then search accordingly but wanted to see if there is an easy approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting the user input to be given directly to the SQL database for processing or is the query coming from somewhere else (like a program, website, or API)?

Comment: Best way to me is to split the input string into a temp table (or table variable) and then do the search by joining the searched table and this new temp table.

Comment: What's the specific database? PostgreSQL, Oracle, MariaDB, etc...

Comment: User enters input into a text field in windows program. I can parse it in my application or split it in stored procedure and perform the search but want to know if there was a simpler approach. Database is sql server.

Comment: If you're going to be including user input in your SQL query, _always_ process and sanitize it before sending it to your database. _Never_ hand raw unfiltered user input directly to your SQL.

Comment: Alternatively, you could concatenate the columns in your database and search based on that, if you have a reliable input format (e.g. always FirstName SingleSpace LastName).